# Running Proxmox VE with a wireless adapter

Tags: debian, wifi, proxmox

I've successfully installed Proxmox and it works perfect while connected via ethernet. The issue arises when trying to get it to detect my wireless adapter.

The wireless card is an ASUS PCE-N53 (Ralink 5592 chipset). I've had no luck with the drivers provided by ASUS. When I try to build the driver from source, it gives me the error:

```
*** No rule to make target 'modules'. Stop.
```

Does anyone have experience with this kind of set up?

I'm new to this game and not sure if it's even possible (obviously it would be better to have it directly connected via ethernet).

Are there any PCI/USB wireless adapters that I'll have less trouble with? If it's not possible with Proxmox, is there any other VE software out there that would fit my use case better (preferably one that can do Windows as well)?

Comment: You can't bridge to a wireless adapter anyway, so you'll have to go wired regardless.

Comment: While @MichaelHampton is right, you _can_ configure routed addressing, but I'm at a loss as to why you'd want your proxmox VMs connecting by something as unreliable as wifi. If it is a single user system (for testing, etc, the only use case I can think of), you would be better off with virtualbox or virt-manager on a regular linux install (an application dedicated to virtualization on a user OS as opposed to installing all the user-mode stuff in an os targeted to virtualization). W.r.t. your question, make sure your linux kernel headers are installed and the kernel source is in /usr/src/linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea.  Following on in my quest to answer questions without answering the OP's question:

You get a Wireless Access Point - one that supports client mode.  I typically use [TP-Link gear](http://uk.tp-link.com/products/details/?categoryid=239&model=TL-WA801ND) for this, mostly because I've got a stockpile of it, and it's pretty inexpensive.

What you do is:

1. Configure the Access Point as a client. (so that it effectively bridges the ethernet to the wifi)
2. Plug the ethernet side into your server.
3. Instant wireless-server.  Without having to mess with linux wifi drivers (which almost never work.)

Comment: Will this act as an actual bridge? Or will my server be running behind an IP address provided by the wireless AP (meaning I would have to configure port forwarding on the WAP)?

Comment: In my experience, you don't need to configure *any* port-forwarding on the WAP, as it's effectively just presenting a wireless adapter - except over ethernet ;)

Comment: Awesome. I'll give this a shot next week :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to install Proxmox VE on my Dell Lattitude laptop. Wifi is working - it is Intel Centrino adapter.

I had to install wpa_supplicant and some other utils to connect to my WPA2 SSID.